# Pandas dataframe add a field based on multiple if statements

Tags: python, lambda

I'm quite new to Python and Pandas so this might be an obvious question.

I have a dataframe with ages listed in it.  I want to create a new field with an age banding.  I can use the lambda statement to capture a single if / else statement but I want to use multiple if's e.g. `if age < 18 then 'under 18' elif age < 40 then 'under 40' else '>40'`.

I don't think I can do this using lambda but am not sure how to do it in a different way.  I have this code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as n

d = {'Age' : pd.Series([36., 42., 6., 66., 38.]) }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['Age_Group'] =  df['Age'].map(lambda x: '<18' if x < 19 else '>18')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The pandas DataFrame provides a nice querying ability.

What you are trying to do can be done simply with:

```
# Set a default value
df['Age_Group'] = '<40'
# Set Age_Group value for all row indexes which Age are greater than 40
df['Age_Group'][df['Age'] > 40] = '>40'
# Set Age_Group value for all row indexes which Age are greater than 18 and < 40
df['Age_Group'][(df['Age'] > 18) & (df['Age'] < 40)] = '>18'
# Set Age_Group value for all row indexes which Age are less than 18
df['Age_Group'][df['Age'] < 18] = '<18'
```

The querying here is a powerful tool of the dataframe and will allow you to manipulate the DataFrame as you need.

For more complex conditionals, you can specify multiple conditions by encapsulating each condition in parenthesis and separating them with a boolean operator ( eg. '&' or '|')

You can see this in work here for the second conditional statement for setting >18.

Edit:

You can read more about indexing of DataFrame and conditionals:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#index-objects

Edit:

To see how it works:

```
>>> d = {'Age' : pd.Series([36., 42., 6., 66., 38.]) }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   Age
0   36
1   42
2    6
3   66
4   38
>>> df['Age_Group'] = '<40'
>>> df['Age_Group'][df['Age'] > 40] = '>40'
>>> df['Age_Group'][(df['Age'] > 18) & (df['Age'] < 40)] = '>18'
>>> df['Age_Group'][df['Age'] < 18] = '<18'
>>> df
   Age Age_Group
0   36       >18
1   42       >40
2    6       <18
3   66       >40
4   38       >18
```

Edit:

To see how to do this without the chaining [using EdChums approach].

```
>>> df['Age_Group'] = '<40'
>>> df.loc[df['Age'] < 40,'Age_Group'] = '<40'
>>> df.loc[(df['Age'] > 18) & (df['Age'] < 40), 'Age_Group'] = '>18'
>>> df.loc[df['Age'] < 18,'Age_Group'] = '<18'
>>> df
   Age Age_Group
0   36       >18
1   42       <40
2    6       <18
3   66       <40
4   38       >18
```

Comment: You should not use chained assignment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy you should do `df.loc[df['Age'] > 40, 'Age_Group'] = '>40'`

Comment: This is true. If the conditional and column to update were switched, it would not update the dataframe, but rather an copy which would be deleted as it is never set back to the original dataframe. However as long as the column to update comes first, then it would have the same effect of using .loc. However, my way is easier to screw up for someone who is new to pandas.

Comment: Thanks - I got both methods to work but I'll go with the unchained method as I take it from the comments that it is the more secure of the 2.

Answer (score 17):

You can also do a nested np.where()

```
df['Age_group'] = np.where(df.Age<18, 'under 18',
                           np.where(df.Age<40,'under 40', '>40'))
```

Comment: Dealing with a codebase that made liberal use of this nesting capability and it's pretty unreadable at this point. So just a general word of caution when using this method.

Comment: What is the benefit of using `np.where`in general? After seeing the solution of Ryan , I wonder when to use np.where at all

Answer (score 0):

[pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) has a [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.case_when.html#janitor.case_when) function (currently in dev) for creating/mutating a column based on conditions; under the hood, it is powered py pandas' `mask` function:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.case_when(
      df.Age.between(18, 40, inclusive='neither'), '>18', # condition, value
      df.Age.lt(18), '<18',                               # condition, value
      '>40',                                              # default, if no matches
      column_name = 'Age_group')

    Age Age_group
0  36.0       >18
1  42.0       >40
2   6.0       <18
3  66.0       >40
4  38.0       >18
```