# Compare two columns using a 2-D Lookup table Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, lookup-tables

This is more of a curiosity question. I recently got involved with using Pandas and thought it would've been really useful when I was in university.

We got given a lookup table.

```
,Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm),Torque(Nm)
Speed,15.0,30.0,45.0,60.0,75.0,90.0,105.0,120.0,135.0,150.0,165.0,180.0
4000,0.6789,0.8672,1.0555,1.2438,1.4321,1.6204,1.8087,1.997,2.1852,2.3735,2.5618,2.7501
3500,0.529,0.6938,0.8585,1.0233,1.188,1.3528,1.5175,1.6823,1.847,2.0118,2.1766,2.2589
3250,0.4701,0.6231,0.7761,0.929,1.082,1.235,1.388,1.541,1.694,1.847,1.9999,2.0382
3000,0.42,0.5612,0.7024,0.8436,0.9849,1.1261,1.2673,1.4085,1.5497,1.691,1.8322,1.8322
2750,0.3773,0.5068,0.6362,0.7657,0.8951,1.0246,1.154,1.2835,1.4129,1.5424,1.6395,1.6395
2500,0.3407,0.4584,0.5761,0.6937,0.8114,0.9291,1.0468,1.1645,1.2822,1.3998,1.4587,1.4587
2250,0.3076,0.4135,0.5194,0.6253,0.7312,0.8371,0.943,1.049,1.1549,1.2608,1.2873,1.2873
2000,0.2759,0.37,0.4642,0.5583,0.6525,0.7466,0.8408,0.9349,1.0291,1.1232,1.1232,1.1232
1750,0.2451,0.3274,0.4098,0.4922,0.5746,0.657,0.7393,0.8217,0.9041,0.9659,0.9659,0.9659
1500,0.2145,0.2851,0.3557,0.4263,0.4969,0.5675,0.6381,0.7087,0.7793,0.8146,0.8146,0.8146
1250,0.1834,0.2423,0.3011,0.3599,0.4188,0.4776,0.5365,0.5953,0.6541,0.6689,0.6689,0.6689
1000,0.1513,0.1984,0.2455,0.2925,0.3396,0.3867,0.4338,0.4808,0.5279,0.5279,0.5279,0.5279
500,0.1513,0.1984,0.2455,0.2925,0.3396,0.3867,0.4338,0.4808,0.5279,0.5279,0.5279,0.5279
50,0.1513,0.1984,0.2455,0.2925,0.3396,0.3867,0.4338,0.4808,0.5279,0.5279,0.5279,0.5279
0,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693,0.5693
```

Then we got given something like this

```
Time(s),Speed(RPM),Torque(Nm)
0,0,0
0.5,0,0
1,0,0
1.5,0,0
2,0,0
2.5,0,0
3,0,0
3.5,0,0
4,0,0
4.5,0,0
5,0,0
5.5,0,0
6,0,0
6.5,0,0
7,0,0
7.5,0,0
8,0,0
8.5,0,0
9,0,0
9.5,0,0
10,0,0
10.5,0,0
11,0,0
11.5,125.3297809,73.08357584
12,250.6595619,73.0969915
12.5,375.9893428,73.11935093
13,501.3191237,73.15065413
13.5,626.6489047,73.1909011
14,751.9786856,73.24009184
14.5,877.3084665,73.29822635
15,1002.638247,73.36530464
15.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
16,1002.638247,7.611470158
16.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
17,1002.638247,7.611470158
17.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
18,1002.638247,7.611470158
18.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
19,1002.638247,7.611470158
19.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
20,1002.638247,7.611470158
20.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
21,1002.638247,7.611470158
21.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
22,1002.638247,7.611470158
22.5,1002.638247,7.611470158
23,1002.638247,7.611470158
23.5,902.3744227,-45.04597555
24,802.110598,-45.09462967
24.5,701.8467732,-45.13755977
25,601.5829485,-45.17476586
25.5,501.3191237,-45.20624793
26,401.055299,-45.232006
26.5,300.7914742,-45.25204004
27,200.5276495,-45.26635008
27.5,100.2638247,-45.2749361
```

Using the lookup table we will look at the vehicle data and find the fuel consumption of the vehicle. I ended up manually looking through the look-up table and finding the fuel consumption (imagine the desperation). I was interested if using pandas its possible to automate looking through the 2-D look-up table and go through the data bases and find the fuel consumption without using the obvious if/else statement.

The closest answer that was somewhat helpful was  [Pandas table lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469399/pandas-table-lookup). Maybe I didn't understand the theory but I can't figure it out

**Initial Idea and some Code**

I thought I could use `pd.melt` to format the lookup table and then using [Pandas table lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469399/pandas-table-lookup) answer to match data with the lookup table.

So far the code looks like this (new to Pandas btw)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('vehicle_data.csv')

#Fuel consumption file
fcf = pd.read_csv('fuel_consumption.csv')

# Converting 2-D Look-up table to a two column and result format
fcf = pd.melt(fcf, id_vars=['Speed'], value_vars=['15.0','30.0','45.0','60.0','75.0','90.0','105.0','120.0','135.0','150.0','165.0','180.0'])

# Converting str to number
fcf['variable'] = pd.to_numeric(fcf['variable'])   
fcf = fcf.rename({'variable':'TorLook'}, axis=1)
fcf = fcf.rename({'value':'Fuel Consumption(g/s)'}, axis=1)

lower_boundary_limit = fcf.loc[0, 'Speed']
upper_boundary_limit = fcf.loc[3, 'Speed']

match = (fcf['Speed'] <= lower_boundary_limit) & (fcf['Speed'] > upper_boundary_limit)

#Creating empty column
fcf['Result'] = ''

result_to_enter = fcf.loc[0, 'Fuel Consumption(g/s)']
fcf['Result'] = fcf['Result'].apply(lambda score: fcf['Speed'][(fcf['Speed'] <= lower_boundary_limit) & (fcf['Speed'] > upper_boundary_limit)].values[0])

# fcf.to_csv('test.csv')
print(fcf)
```

**Output**

```
     Speed  TorLook  Fuel Consumption(g/s)  Result
0     4000     15.0                 0.6789    4000
1     3500     15.0                 0.5290    4000
2     3250     15.0                 0.4701    4000
3     3000     15.0                 0.4200    4000
4     2750     15.0                 0.3773    4000
..     ...      ...                    ...     ...
175   1250    180.0                 0.6689    4000
176   1000    180.0                 0.5279    4000
177    500    180.0                 0.5279    4000
178     50    180.0                 0.5279    4000
179      0    180.0                 0.5693    4000
```

Comment: Please take the time to add your data in a format that enable us to answer your question without manually building the table.

Comment: Added it  now @academy-

Comment: Your sample data doesn't quite look right.  Is the lookup table supposed to a single speed column or something?

Comment: I've corrected the look-up table @Chris

Comment: I imagine something with `pd.merge_as_of` will do. However, I can't really test it as your sample data is way too complicated. Can you simplify them? This doesn't need/have to be your actual data. Can you make something similar as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Comment: I suppose I could make it simpler i.e 1d lookup table and go from there. So there's no native lookup table functionality in Pandas? I know MATLAB/SIMULINK have this https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/2dlookuptable.html